# Paperclip - Image Uploading Error: " not recognized by the 'identify' command."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I use *Rails 3* and *paperclip*. My logic allows user to upload an image. That works fine unless the user selects a file that is not an image.

If the user picks a text file, for instance, validation passes but ends up with this error:

```
5 errors prohibited the profile update:

Profile pic content type is not one of image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-17xuiu4-0.js is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-17xuiu4-0.js is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-17xuiu4-0.js is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-17xuiu4-0.js is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

At least the first error refers to the file type. But if the user uploads some more specific file, like a `.PXM`, then Rails behaves strange and shows this:

```
4 errors prohibited the profile update:

Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-1scwkg7-0.pxm is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-1scwkg7-0.pxm is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-1scwkg7-0.pxm is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Profile pic /var/folders/lF/lF0Ne5vGFj44kV54W3zBdU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20101118-229-1scwkg7-0.pxm is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I have the following code in my model:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :profile_pic, :content_type=>['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
```

...and this paperclip initializer:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin/"
```

ImageMagik appears to be installed and set up correctly:

```
$ which Magick-config
/opt/local/bin/Magick-config
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `which identify`, `locate identify` or `find / -name identify` return?

Comment: $ which identify
/opt/local/bin/identify

Comment: I fixed this with cocaine 0.3.2. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753157/paperclipnotidentifiedbyimagemagickerror-in-spreeadminimagescontrollercre/12771707#12771707

Comment: Please, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771707/1472432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with Paperclip and Rails 2.3.8.
In your Model's `has_attached_file` declaration, remove the `:styles` for any non-image files.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the code below on model. It will not process non-image file.

```
before_post_process :image?
def image?
  !(data_content_type =~ /^image.*/).nil?
end
```