# Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Spree::Admin::ImagesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, spree

I am attempting to setup Spree for the first time. Everything was going well until I hit the image upload. I have installed Imageamgick using homebrew on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. Uploading any image gives me the following error.

```
Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Spree::Admin::ImagesController#create

    Command :: identify -format %wx%h :file
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/fq/9g_6hmg513g6137rb6sbghw00000gn/T/stream20121005-26943-16883d4.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>

Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError (/var/folders/fq/9g_6hmg513g6137rb6sbghw00000gn/T/stream20121005-26943-16883d4.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.):
  paperclip (2.7.1) lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:29:in `from_file'
  spree_core (1.2.0) app/models/spree/image.rb:35:in `find_dimensions'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1794851703999987262__post_process__1580526166879208018__callbacks'
```

When I run identify from the command line I get the following output

```
    Image Settings:
  -alpha option        on, activate, off, deactivate, set, opaque, copy
                       transparent, extract, background, or shape
  -antialias           remove pixel-aliasing
  -authenticate password
                       decipher image with this password
  -channel type        apply option to select image channels
  -colorspace type     alternate image colorspace
  -crop geometry       cut out a rectangular region of the image
  -define format:option
                       define one or more image format options
  -density geometry    horizontal and vertical density of the image
  -depth value         image depth
  -extract geometry    extract area from image
  -features distance   display image features (e.g. contrast, correlation)
  -format "string"     output formatted image characteristics
  -fuzz distance       colors within this distance are considered equal
  -gamma value         of gamma correction
  -interlace type      type of image interlacing scheme
  -interpolate method  pixel color interpolation method
  -limit type value    pixel cache resource limit
  -monitor             monitor progress
  -ping                efficiently determine image attributes
  -quiet               suppress all warning messages
  -regard-warnings     pay attention to warning messages
  -respect-parentheses settings remain in effect until parenthesis boundary
  -sampling-factor geometry
                       horizontal and vertical sampling factor
  -seed value          seed a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers
  -set attribute value set an image attribute
  -size geometry       width and height of image
  -strip               strip image of all profiles and comments
  -unique              display the number of unique colors in the image
  -units type          the units of image resolution
  -verbose             print detailed information about the image
  -virtual-pixel method
                       virtual pixel access method

Image Operators:
  -negate              replace every pixel with its complementary color 

Miscellaneous Options:
  -debug events        display copious debugging information
  -help                print program options
  -list type           print a list of supported option arguments
  -log format          format of debugging information
  -version             print version information

By default, the image format of `file' is determined by its magic
number.  To specify a particular image format, precede the filename
with an image format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the
image type as the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps).  Specify 'file' as
'-' for standard input or output.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My error was - “**Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Spree::Admin::ImagesController**”

I fixed this error some days ago.

Before that I tried:

- Update XCode (with Command-Line Tools)
- Update Imagemagick (i tried it from source and as binary module)
- Update MacPort
- Used Brew (refreshing with all dependencies for Imagemagic,
  used “brew doctor”), not MacPort
- Reinstall all gems that use Imagemagick
- Bundle update
- etc

And sure I had my “Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:command_path]” option in production.rb file pointing to Imagemagick bin folder.

Several times i did it from a to z, again and again.

But nothing could help me.

By the way, *in all cases i had worked fine “convert”, “identify” and “display” with test images* of any kind, but not in my rails app (spree app).

I dived dipper and tried to do research inside rails console with

```
Paperclip.run("identify", "-format %m :file", :file => "/path/to/image”)
```

as paperclip do. And only new format (cocaine 0.4) of this command:

```
Paperclip.run("identify", "-format %m /path/to/image")
```

worked fine!!!

As a result, i found that **cocaine 0.4 is the source of my problem**. I tried downgrade to cocaine 0.3.2 in my Gemfile and my Spree app start working!!!

All i need to do is **use cocaine 0.3.2 instead of 0.4**!!!

Comment: Thanks Leonid that fixed the issue. Have you submited a bug report to Spree and/or cocaine projects?

Comment: Also you probably can upgrade from paperclip 2.7 to 2.8 to fix it

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it didn't try to tell a story for so long before providing the answer. Give the answer up front, and provide some background after if you feel it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check if png format is in the list of compiled formats of identify:

```
identify -list format
```

If it's not, you might have to recompile it with these options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes
```

Comment: It appears to be PNG24* PNG       rw-   opaque 24-bit RGB (zlib 1.2.5)
    PNG32* PNG       rw-   opaque or transparent 32-bit RGBA
     PNG8* PNG       rw-   8-bit indexed with optional binary transparency

Comment: I upgraded my installation of imagemagick via homebrew, and it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

Also I met the problem when image file doesn't exists in public folder.
**I've just copied a random file** with the same name and everything started work.

```
parepclip 2.7.5 cocain 0.3.2
```